# Combining data of multiple folders

Tags: python, pandas, loops, file

I have two folders (Q & P) of files (>10) with data. I want to automatically analyse all matching files within the folders. This means P1 & Q1 , P5 & Q5 etc. I have no errors, but I do not get the results I want. I think this is because my loop does not memorise the intermediate steps (only does operations for the last file in the folders), is this correct? How can I analyse all matching files after my initial loops for the folders? Help is much appriciated!

```
p = [] #empty list for results precipiation loop
q = [] #empty list for results discharge loop

#Preciptation folder read 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:TSA_P"):
    for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        with open(file_path) as file:
            file = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=' ', header=None, skiprows=1, names=['year','month','day','precipitation_cpc'])
            file.columns = file.columns.str.replace(' ', ',')
            file.loc[:,'dt'] = pd.to_datetime(file[['year', 'month', 'day']])
            file.index = file['dt']
            file.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day','Rain','dt']
            p.append(file)
            
#file.head()

#Discharge folder read
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\TSA_Q"):
    for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        with open(file_path) as f:
            f = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=' ', header=None, skiprows=1, names=['year','month','day','streamflow_m3s', 'qual_control_by_ana', 'qual_flag'])
            f.columns = f.columns.str.replace(' ', ',')
            f.loc[:,'dt'] = pd.to_datetime(f[['year', 'month', 'day']])
            f.index = f['dt']
            f.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day','Discharge','Quality','Flag','dt']
            f = f.loc[(f.index.year>=1980)]
            q.append(file)
#f.head()

#Part C
C = pd.DataFrame() #Data P & Q per catchment
Format = (24*3600) #mm/d to mm/s
C['Psum'] = file['Rain'].resample('Y').sum()/Format #Daily to yearly
C['Qsum'] = f['Discharge'].resample('Y').sum() #Daily to yearly
#C.head()
```

Comment: To do this kind of thing a first approach can be to create an empty list before the loop, and at each iteration of the loop you add the element you just calculated. then you have a list of all calculated elements.

Comment: Thanks, but how I can then proceed to do Part C (see script) for each element of the loop? I now have created two lists (for P and for Q) , but how can I let them interact with each other for Part C?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use 'replace'.
If You have every same filenames, replacing path of P will find the pair Q file.
(for example: C:\TSA_P\1.csv - C:\TSA_Q\1.csv)

If This doesn't work, Tell us more about this problem.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

C = pd.DataFrame()  # Data P & Q per catchment
Format = (24 * 3600)  # mm/d to mm/s

# Preciptation folder read
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\\TSA_P"):
    for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename) # file path: P path
        with open(file_path) as file:
            file = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=' ', header=None, skiprows=1,
                               names=['year', 'month', 'day', 'precipitation_cpc'])
            file.columns = file.columns.str.replace(' ', ',')
            file.loc[:, 'dt'] = pd.to_datetime(file[['year', 'month', 'day']])
            file.index = file['dt']
            file.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'Rain', 'dt']
        # file: content of P

        file_path = file_path.replace('TSA_P', 'TSA_Q') # file path: Q path
        with open(file_path) as f:
            f = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=' ', header=None, skiprows=1,
                            names=['year', 'month', 'day', 'streamflow_m3s', 'qual_control_by_ana', 'qual_flag'])
            f.columns = f.columns.str.replace(' ', ',')
            f.loc[:, 'dt'] = pd.to_datetime(f[['year', 'month', 'day']])
            f.index = f['dt']
            f.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'Discharge', 'Quality', 'Flag', 'dt']
            f = f.loc[(f.index.year >= 1980)]
        # f: content of Q

        # Part C
        C['Psum'] = file['Rain'].resample('Y').sum() / Format  # Daily to yearly
        C['Qsum'] = f['Discharge'].resample('Y').sum()  # Daily to yearly
```